# How to Post request API in do loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest-client

I wanted to send multiple single requests inside a do loop and get the response. Everything working fine except that, after some time the loop itself initializing another loop of requests, So there will be duplicate results. This duplicate looping is kept on coming in the way.

Thanks in Advance

```rb
  def method 
  @csvdata.each do |d|
  params1 = d
    url = "https://something?"
       headers = { accept: :json}
       begin
         results = RestClient.post url, params1, headers
         @result_body = JSON.parse(results.body)
         @checks.push(@result_body.first[1])
         puts d[:id].to_s + "  " + @result_body.first[1]
       rescue Exception => e
         @checks.push("Error")
         puts e
       end
    end
   puts @checks
  end
```

The actual result should be like

1. Id     Score
2. 1141   100.00
3. 1142   12.00

...

But the result I am getting is

```
 Id   Score
  1.  1141  100.00
  2.  1142   12.00 ... 
120.  1261  36.00
  1.  1141  100.00  (loop starting again while the current one is 
           still running)
121. 1262  29.00
  2. 1142   12.00
122. 1263  45.00..
```

Comment: Is that your actual code?  There isn't a loop...?  How is this being run, script at the cli, call to a server endpoint...?

Comment: Please see the edited. I am using rest-client Gem

Comment: Is `@csvdata` a hash, our some type of custom/library class?  Have you verified that the duplicates don't exist in that container?

Comment: Yes there are no duplicates in that.                                                                  
                                                                                                           
   def set_csvdata
      @csvdata = Model.where.not(zipcode: [nil,""])
   end

Comment: How long does this method take to execute?  It is possible that a client is attempting to retry because it didn't get a response... Add a puts before the loop.

Comment: You are correct, That's what I initially thought. And wondering are there any alternatives for this.

Comment: Two options I can think of 1. look into making it a background or long running task and then return a 202 or maybe 100 2. Break it into smaller chunks so it doesn't run as long.